# Yard graph places class outside of it's module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class-diagram, yard, yardoc

I have a ruby project with a module and a class defined in the module:

- a.rb
- a/b.rb

File a.rb contains:

```
require 'a/b'
module A
end
```

File a/b.rb contains:

```
module A
  class B
  end
end
```

When I run `yardoc **` and then `yard graph --full --dependencies | dot -T pdf -o doc/diagram.pdf`, the resulting pdf contains class B, which is outside of module A.

However, in HTML files generated by yardoc the class B is correctly placed inside the module A.

[image: Diagram]
How can I configure Yard such that the class B will be placed inside the module A?

Comment: There is no relationship between class `B` and module `A`. Ruby doesn't have nested classes like Beta or Newspeak. The *constant* `B` lives inside the namespace of module `A`, but the class *itself* which is referenced by that constant has no relationship to module `A`. The only relationship that classes have in Ruby, is to their superclass. So, the diagram is entirely correct.